# Eclipse CDT doesn't clear errors from previous builds

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Since upgrading to Eclipse Juno (Eclipse CDT 6), I've noticed that, when I do a "make" for my makefile projects, errors from previous builds such as the following don't get cleared from my "Problems" list:

```
make: *** [Debug] Error 2
make[1]: *** [util.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [record.o] Error 1
```

The individual compiler error messages from previous builds are cleared just fine, but the final, summary error messages that `make` prints whenever it encounters any errors are not.

How do I get Eclipse to clear these errors as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently Eclipse CDT 6 has introduced a new Make parser.  To start using it:

- Go under Project, under Options.
- Go under the C++ Build category, under Settings.
- Under the Error Parsers tab, uncheck "CDT GNU Make Error Parser 6.0 (Deprecated)" and check "CDT GNU Make Error Parser 7.0."
- Right-click on any remaining error messages from previous builds under the GNU Make Error Parser 6.0 and manually delete them.

Comment: FYI, didn't do anything for me.  v6 wasn't checked and errors are still not cleared on new builds.  The problem just keeps coming back.

Comment: You might need to restart Eclipse so it will allow you to delete old error messages.  (For me, the delete option was greyed-out until I restarted.)

Answer (score 2):

Just select the error messages in the "Problems" view and hit [Del] :-)

Comment: This works, although it's something of a nuisance to do every time a build fails.

Comment: (plus one) Yup - I really expect the build problems to be auto-cleared when I start a new build